# Running a script added after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add the pages later for my project, but after adding the script tag at the bottom is not executed.

Main

```js
const fetch = (url, call) => {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         call(xhttp);
      }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

const UpdatePage = page_name => {
  fetch(`/app/${page_name}`, (data => {
    App.innerHTML = data.responseText;
  }))
}
```

Code of new page

```
<div>
    <%= showId %>
</div>

<script>console.log("Welcome to somewhere")</script>
```

Page loads sucessfuly but the javascript not be executed. How i can execute the script tag on new page added?

Comment: can't see your all code but it is possible that your javascript runs before the page loads. you may need to adjust the timing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really understand your question.
From what I did though you want to run the script after the page has loaded.

For that you can use the defer tag

```
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

Read this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You must call the function

```
fetch();
UpdatePage();
```

Before doing this, you must call your file `js` in the `ejs` file